# HTTP proxy error in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, junit, http-proxy

I have been trying to install Android Studio in many PCs.

In some PCs, I have come across the *HTTP proxy* error and *offline sync* issue. Due to this, I  had to uninstall and reinstall the whole studio. While this method worked fine in some, in others the problem persisted.

Is there any problem with the offline installation
 or 
Is internet connection mandatory for the installation of Android Studio without any errors?

There is also another prominent error while opening new project, *junit::junit*.

I am a beginner so kindly keep it in mind while you answer me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

put `useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'` in build.gradle like below code and rebuild your project;

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.user.appname"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
lintOptions {
    checkReleaseBuilds false
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}
```